# entity framework unidirectional association from one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, associations, one-to-many

I have an Account class which will be used to indicate who is responsible for a certain entity. There will be many entities where this will be used, so I don't want to pollute my Account class with all these collections

```
public class Account
{
   public Guid Id{get; set;}
   public Guid Name{get; set;}
   ...
   public class EntityConfiguration : EntityConfigurationBase<Account>
   {   
       public EntityConfiguration()
       {
           // I do not want these!
           HasMany(a => a.As)   
              .WithOptional(x => x.Account)
              .HasForeignKey(x =>x.AccountKey);
            }
        }
    }
}


public class A 
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public Account Account{get; set;}
   // FK-Nav property
   public Guid AccountKey{get;set;}
   public class EntityConfiguration : EntityConfigurationBase<A>
   {   
       public EntityConfiguration()
       {
           // what should go here to specify the association to Account?
           ????
        }
    }
}

public class B 
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public Account Account{get; set;}
   // FK-Nav property
   public Guid AccountKey{get;set;}
      public class EntityConfiguration : EntityConfigurationBase<B>
   {   
       public EntityConfiguration()
       {
           // what should go here to specify the association to Account?
           ????
        }
    }

}

etc.
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a fit but have you considered custom code first conventions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx

Comment: @Colin I don't think those are present in my version of E.F. yet. I'm using 5.0 with .Net 4.5 (visual studio 2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class A 
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}

   public Account Account{get; set;}
   // FK-Nav property
   public Guid AccountKey{get;set;}
   public class EntityConfiguration : EntityConfigurationBase<A>
   {   
       public EntityConfiguration()
       {

           HasOptional(x => x.Account).HasMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.AccountKey);
        }
    }
}
```